# Checkout path is not empty. Do you want to delete its contents? Xamarin/Git

Tags: c#, git, xamarin, xamarin.ios

When I was trying to add my Xamarin Solution to a git repository. Not knowing really what I was doing I was doing a "Checkout". I then received a message that stated

"Checkout path is not empty. Do you want to delete its contents?"

I pressed ok on this message and now all my solution files are missing? Is there a way to recover these files or are they gone forever?

If I can recover the files how would I go about doing that.

Thank you!

Comment: this was adding it for the first time? that means you never got do a single commit neither add the files on stage?

Comment: @apineda Yeah that is correct. I know that I was missing some steps, but wasnt paying attention when I clicked "Ok" on the pop-up.

Comment: @scouty Did you every find a solution to this? I'm in the same boat :/