# Checkout path is not empty. Do you want to delete its contents?

Tags: macos, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am configuring TFS on mac but while configuration I got popup with **Checkout path is not empty. Do you want to delete its contents?**

And default path is my project path which is not configure with tfs. When I Click on **Yes** button it deleted all my project. So I have tried 2-3 software to recover the deleted project but I am not able to recover it.

the project path is under **MAC HD>>users>>UserName>>Projects**

Please suggest me how I can recover this project not in tfs but deleted when Checkout path is not empty.

Comment: Are you just using Xamarin Studio? This popup seems not related to TFS. Tfs didn't have the similar mechanism. There is a same issue also occurs on git https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42381359/checkout-path-is-not-empty-do-you-want-to-delete-its-contents-xamarin-git. The issue is more related to **Xamarin**, you need to ask the support for Xamarin team.

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT yes you are right. whole code is deleted which is I implemented for 1 year. need to get any solution on it